# How to decompile the dotnet code in dotnet reflactor after trial expired

Tags: decompiler

i need to use the dotnet reflactor to decompile my dotnet cod . but as its trial is expired it dpoes not allow me to reuse.i tried to uninstall but not worked . i do not want to use the jet brains and dev extras as they are not comfortable to me in use . Is there any way to use it  ? please help.

pooja

Comment: No way, since it is expired. Also, off topic for StackOverflow. You can try the free tool `ILSpy` which does the good job, just like reflector.

Comment: what if someone change the ip of system and reintsall the software

Comment: I don't know. But think it in other way, those guys who wrote reflector should be very smart, they make it very hard for anyone who try to crack their products. I don't think changing IP address works.

Comment: To use .NET Reflector after the trial has expired, use [this web site](http://www.red-gate.com/Dynamic/purchase/product/.netreflector).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reinstall the red gate software after trial expired by doing these:

1. uninstall the older one.

2. delete the browing history.

 
3. I have taken the setup from another computer and simply install that. 
it provide me to use the software again for 14 days.

Pooja